# CSS background configuring

Tags: html, css

Here's the image:

[image]

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>FLoung</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">      
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #cfcfcf;
                font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size:12px;
                color:#666666;
                text-decoration: none; 
            }

            #wrapper {
                width: 700px;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 5px;
                margin-top: 75px;               
            }

        </style>    

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

            Test

        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

how would I go about doing the second dark layered background? the top part is light grey, how would I go about doing the bottom part dark?

Would I just create a new div, with a z-index?

Comment: You can you slice the image into two and have two divs with different background colors

Answer (score 3):

You could just split the wrapper `div` into two divs with different background colours

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wdjfH/)